# How would I set my Ubuntu 15.10 desktop up as a file sharing server for a home network?

Tags: dual-boot, server

All I'm trying to do is set up a home network and link the three coputers to the one Ubuntu computer for file sharing and storage. The Ubuntu pc (My personal PC) has 500gig internal and will be hooked up the a 1TB external for storage.

Comment: I'm afraid this is too broad for this site. We deal with more specific questions. That said, why do you want to install Ubuntu Server and dual boot with your normal OS? Why not just use your normal OS for this? There's no reason to install the server version. Anyway, try editing your question and asking about one specific aspect of what you are trying to do. I don't know what you mean by "securing emails" but everything else you describe only requires setting up a [samba share](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba).

Comment: I didn't know that, I figured setting up the server was the way I would go. If I can just use my regular Ubuntu OS for the same thing and by securing email I just mean having it on the linux and safely stored rather than on the windows 8 pc, since she downloads all of her emails using mozilla or something

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Much better, OK, did you have a look at the samba guide I linked to in my previous comment? That should answer all of your questions.

Comment: I'm looking it over now; I'm not very experienced as a CL user and that's my focus right now, so I have to check and recheck everything. Thank you though, making me rephrase my question here helped me to rephrase it in my head and I think I've worked a solution for my other PC's